# XJC with Krasa Plugin

Tags: ant, jaxb, xjc

Hello i get a build error when i execute the following ant-script. Can somebody help me to resolve the problem?

ANT output:

```
Buildfile: D:\workspace\Webformular2\WebContent\WEB-INF\XSD-Pfad.ant 

[delete] Deleting directory D:\workspace\Webformular2\WebContent\WEB-INF\src 
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\workspace\Webformular2\WebContent\WEB-INF\src xjc: 
[xjc] Consider using <depends>/<produces> so that XJC won't do unnecessary compilation
[xjc] Compiling file:/D:/workspace/Webformular2/WebCo ntent/WEB-INF/jaxb/antragsdaten.xsd and others

BUILD FAILED D:\workspace\Webformular2\WebContent\WEB-INF\XSD-Pfad.ant:11: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/constraints/NotNull
```

Ant script

```
<project default="xjc">
        <delete dir="src"/>
        <mkdir dir="src" />
        <target name="xjc" description="JAXB Generation">
                <taskdef name="xjc" classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask">
                  <classpath>
                    <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar" />
                  </classpath>
                </taskdef>`
`
                <xjc destdir="src" extension="true">
                        <schema  dir="jaxb" includes="*.xsd"/>
                        <arg line="
                                        -XJsr303Annotations
                                        -XReplacePrimitives"/>
                </xjc>
        </target>
</project>`
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take some time to read how questions can be formated using Markdown and don't split your question across an answer.

Answer (score 0):

------- Ant-Skript ---------
`<project default="xjc">
        <delete dir="src"/>
        <mkdir dir="src" />
        <target name="xjc" description="JAXB Generation">
                <taskdef name="xjc" classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask">
                  <classpath>
                    <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar" />
                  </classpath>
                </taskdef>`

                `<xjc destdir="src" extension="true">
                        <schema  dir="jaxb" includes="*.xsd"/>
                        <arg line="
                                        -XJsr303Annotations
                                        -XReplacePrimitives"/>
                </xjc>
        </target>
</project>`

Comment: Delete this. Include your script with the question, don't slit it across with an answer

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the "validation-api.jar" in your lib directory.

Reference:

- [Maven Central search for missing class "javax/validation/constraints/NotNull"](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3a%22javax.validation.constraints.NotNull%22)